# JavaScript object oriented audio player not working

Tags: javascript, oop, audio-player

I'm building a object oriented audio player in JavaScript. This is my code so far:

```js
var audio1 = new Audio("http://jplayer.org/audio/m4a/Miaow-07-Bubble.m4a", "audio/mpeg");

function Audio(src, type) {
    //create audioElement
    this.audioElement = document.createElement("audio");
    this.audioElement.setAttribute("src", src);
    this.audioElement.setAttribute("type", type);
    document.getElementById("main").appendChild(this.audioElement);

    //create audioControls
    this.audioControls = document.createElement("div");
    this.audioControls.setAttribute("class", "play button");
    document.getElementById("main").appendChild(this.audioControls);
   
    this.playing = false;
    
    this.audioControls.onclick = function () {
        if (this.playing) {
            this.pause();
        } else {
            this.play();        
        }
    }
    
    this.play = function() {
        this.audioElement.play();
        this.playing = true;
        this.audioControls.setAttribute("class", "pause button");
    };
    
    this.pause = function() {
        this.audioElement.pause();
        this.playing = false;
        this.audioControls.setAttribute("class", "play button");
    };
}
```

```css
@font-face {
    font-family:"Ionicons";
    src:url("http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/fonts/ionicons.eot?v=2.0.1");
    src:url("http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/fonts/ionicons.eot?v=2.0.1#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/fonts/ionicons.ttf?v=2.0.1") format("truetype"), url("http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/fonts/ionicons.woff?v=2.0.1") format("woff"), url("http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/fonts/ionicons.svg?v=2.0.1#Ionicons") format("svg");
    font-weight:normal;
    font-style:normal;
}
.button {
    font-family:"Ionicons";
    font-size:48px;
}
.play:before {
    content:'\f488'
}
.pause:before {
    content:'\f478'
}
```

```html
<div id="main"></div>
```

The play button is displayed correctly, but when clicking it I get an error in my console that says:
TypeError: this.play is not a function

So I guess the error is that I can't access methods of the class from another method.
I would be very thankful for a hint how to solve this!

Comment: `Audio` is already a defined JavaScript object implemented by the browser. I would consider using a different name for your class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Event handlers `this` context refers to the element that fired the event.

You can fix this by using the classic `var that = this` construct.

```js
var audio1 = new Audio("http://jplayer.org/audio/m4a/Miaow-07-Bubble.m4a", "audio/mpeg");

function Audio(src, type) {
    //create audioElement
    this.audioElement = document.createElement("audio");
    this.audioElement.setAttribute("src", src);
    this.audioElement.setAttribute("type", type);
    document.getElementById("main").appendChild(this.audioElement);

    //create audioControls
    this.audioControls = document.createElement("div");
    this.audioControls.setAttribute("class", "play button");
    document.getElementById("main").appendChild(this.audioControls);
   
    this.playing = false;


    var that = this;

    this.audioControls.onclick = function () {
        if (that.playing) {
            that.pause();
        } else {
            that.play();        
        }
    }
    
    this.play = function() {
        this.audioElement.play();
        this.playing = true;
        this.audioControls.setAttribute("class", "pause button");
    };
    
    this.pause = function() {
        this.audioElement.pause();
        this.playing = false;
        this.audioControls.setAttribute("class", "play button");
    };
}
```

```css
@font-face {
    font-family:"Ionicons";
    src:url("http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/fonts/ionicons.eot?v=2.0.1");
    src:url("http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/fonts/ionicons.eot?v=2.0.1#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/fonts/ionicons.ttf?v=2.0.1") format("truetype"), url("http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/fonts/ionicons.woff?v=2.0.1") format("woff"), url("http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/fonts/ionicons.svg?v=2.0.1#Ionicons") format("svg");
    font-weight:normal;
    font-style:normal;
}
.button {
    font-family:"Ionicons";
    font-size:48px;
}
.play:before {
    content:'\f488'
}
.pause:before {
    content:'\f478'
}
```

```html
<div id="main"></div>
```